# Using cluster-algorithms-java-alpha library java to determine Silhouette Index

Tags: java, eclipse, cluster-analysis

I am trying to use the source code from the cluster-algorithms-java-alpha library this is the link "http://code.google.com/p/cluster-algorithms-java-alpha/source/browse/tags/rewritepending/src/validationIndices/SilhouetteIndex.java?r=6".

but I am really confused on how to get the input for the method which is "calculateIndex(Dataset clusteredData)". I will integrate this code with the java ml library.
So I will apply k-means clustering using java ml library and use the code from the above link to determine the right number of clusters but my problem is how to get the input type "Dataset clusteredData" any suggestion?

Comment: why use **abandoned** software marked as "needs rewrite"? (java-ml seems to be abandoned by its sole author, too) you are trying to put a flat tire onto a crashed car.

Comment: What You suggest to use for data clustering I used java ml because I could implement it in my code I think weka is the most popular but I think its GUI more than a library

Comment: For clustering algorithms in Java, ELKI is currently the tool or choice (and it does see updates pretty continuously). I think it has Silhouette, you only need to enable it. As it uses pairwise distances, it is more expensive to compute than the actual algorithms.

Comment: Anony-Mousse thanks for replying but this is what is written on the ELKI website "The ELKI team advocates to not embed it in other applications Java (yet) for a number of reasons" Based on this I think its not suitable to be implemented in java Any Recommendation?

Comment: They don't recommend it, because they still change the APIs. But it works well, just don't expect a smooth upgrade to the next version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is InputReader defined for reading content of a file:

https://code.google.com/p/cluster-algorithms-java-alpha/source/browse/tags/rewritepending/src/input/InputReader.java?r=6

If it is not enough for your needs you can use it as a template to initlize your own Dataset